# Reverse for 'operation_info' with keyword arguments '{'id_operation': ''}' not found

Tags: django

I had this problem while trying to pass arguments through the template

this is my urls.py

`path('Operation/Info/<id_operation>',views.operation_info,name='operation_info'),`

and this is my template

```
{% for o in operation_list %}
                <tr><td><a href="{% url 'operation_info' id_operation=c.id %}">link</a></td></tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

this is my view :

```
def caravane_info(request,id_caravane):
    connected = request.user.is_authenticated
    if connected:
       U_ID = request.user.id
       F = Membre.objects.get(userr_id=U_ID)
       bureau_level = F.Grade_bureau
    caravane = Caravane.objects.get(id=id_caravane)
    return render(request,'Bureau/operation_info.html',locals())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you use:

```
{% url 'operation_info' id_operation=c.id %}
```

but `c` is not a variable in scope. The name of the variable is `o`, so:

```
{% url 'operation_info' id_operation=o.id %}
```

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* make use of `locals()` when you pass variables to the
> `render(…)` function, it makes it unclear exactly what you
> pass to the template. This makes it harder to debug templates, and the IDE
> can not help to determine what variables are for example useless, it is better
> to use an explicit dictionary.